# Error en bucle for: "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean"

Tags: java, booleano, números-enteros

soy nuevo en StackOverflow y también programando en Java. Estoy pasando ejercicios que hice en pseudocodigo a Java, y me encuentro con un error que no puedo solucionar en el bucle for.

La idea del ejercicio es crear un vector que contenga butacas de cine libres y ocupadas, luego recorrer el vector y devolver la cantidad de butacas ocupadas.

Transcribo el codigo:

```
public class butacasdecine {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int [] butacas = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
    int contador = 0;


    for (int i=0; i=11; i++)
    {
       if (butacas[i]==1);
       contador++;          
    }
  System.out.println("Butacas ocupadas: " +contador);
}
```

El error aparece en la linea del ´for (int i=0...´ y dice textualmente: "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean

The assigned value is never used"

Gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El segundo parámetro del bucle debe de ser una condición. Por lo tanto, ahora mismo estás haciendo una asignación y es por eso por lo que te está dando error diciéndote que esperaba un valor booleano (`true` o `false`, resultado de una condición).

Deberías de usar los símbolos `>`, `<`, `<=` , `>=` o `==`.

Ejemplo:

```
for (int i=0; i<=11; i++)
```

En este caso por ejemplo recorrería todos los números comprendidos entre el 0 y el 11, ambos inclusive (ya que tiene el `=`).

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Debes modificar la condicion booleada de tu for : tu codigo debe quedar asi :

```
public class butacasdecine {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int [] butacas = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
    int contador = 0;


    for (int i=0; i<=11; i++)
    {
       if (butacas[i]==1);
       contador++;          
    }
  System.out.println("Butacas ocupadas: " +contador);
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar un forEach para recorrer el array con las butacas y así ir comparando en cada iteración si el valor es igual a 1, aumentando el contador si esta condición se cumple, Te dejo el código, igual de todas formas seria buena practica realizar Test con Junit ayuda demasiado a la hora de programar algoritmos como estos.

```
@Test
public void validarButacasTest() {

    int[] butacas = { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 };
    int contador = 0;

    for (int i : butacas) {
        if (i == 1)
            contador++;
    }

    Assert.assertThat(contador, is(7));
}
```

Incluso lo puedes hacer la comparación con expresiones lambda y stream, queda mas simple y entendible.

```
@Test
public void validarButacasTest() {

    Integer[] butacas = { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 };
    int contador = (int) Arrays.asList(butacas).stream().filter(b -> b == 1).count();

    Assert.assertThat(contador, is(8));
}
```